# How to enable fingerprint option in my Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS? (Asus VivoBook S15)

Tags: 20.04, asus, fingerprint-reader

**In the user's there is no**

> *Fingerprint Login*

**option there.**

I want to unlock my device with my fingerprint.

Comment: I might be wrong on this, but isn't this a new feature in Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: The VivoBook uses a fingerprint reader from ELAN, which is not yet supported. That said, [work is being done to reverse-engineer the driver](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/136#note_590741) so, hopefully, there will be support for the device in the near future.